# Trouble passing two different intents to an activity

Tags: android

Basically I have a screen that will either add or update a user contact information. The problem is I HAVE to use the same screen to do both things.

When a user selects "new" I simply pass the intent like this:

```
newButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ContactProjectActivity.this, AddContact.class);
                startActivity(intent);  
            }
        });
```

From a seperate activity, when the user selects "edit" I pass the intent like this:

```
edit.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ContactView.this, AddContact.class);
            intent.putExtra("name",personName.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }

});
```

On the New/Edit page I have this code:

```
final Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String searchTerm = extras.getString("name");

        if (extras.size() > 0) {
            int index = searchTerm.indexOf(' ');
            final String fName = searchTerm.substring(0, index);
            final String lName = searchTerm.substring(index + 1, searchTerm.length());
```

With this code, I'm checking to see which activity is coming to my page. If I had information passed to me, I know I am supposed to edit the data.

The problem is, when I click the newButton in the ContactProjectActivity class my program crashes.

Comment: What's the error that you're getting in the logcat? developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you AddContact.class,you should have used:

```
String searchTerm="";
if(getIntent().hasExtra("name"))
     searchTerm= getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
```

instead of using

```
final Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String searchTerm = extras.getString("name");
```

Comment: I have to declare the Bundle to use 'extras.getString("name");

Comment: no....you can directly use the lines i had written above,no need of Bundle object.

Comment: I had to write searchTerm = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name"); but it still isn't helping me.

Comment: please check it now.this is done.i have tested it.and sorry for my lots of mistakes.:)

Answer (score 1):

on New/Edit Page, just check whether you are getting Extras of not.

```
if(extras!=null)
{
   String searchTerm = extras.getString("name");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Intent's `boolean hasExtra(String name)` method to check whether you have Extras or not.